# tomcat + openshift + liferay = request lost all my headers randomly

Tags: tomcat, cookies, liferay, openshift

I have one problem in my liferay application, but i think that, in this case, liferay haven't any responsability in fail. Randomly (I suposse depends of the work charge) my requests last all headers. Problem started in tomcat7, and i decided add traces to tomcat code for be able to corner this issue... i added trace to tomcat 8.0.24, in CoyoteAdapter class, metehod parseSessionCookiesId (because initially I thinked my problem was only with JSESSIONID). At method end I have added this line:

```
ServerCookies serverCookies = request.getServerCookies();
int count = serverCookies.getCookieCount();

if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
  log.debug(" (sn3) This request have  [" + count + "] cookies");
}
```

Ok! Only fails in production environment, put traces, launch one test pile (with connection:close for avoid keep-alive problems...) and in request number 35500 i obtain this trace:

```
Sep 13, 2018 8:07:13 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer parseRequestLine
FINE: Received [GET /Theme_INESPCORP-theme/css/main.css?browserId=firefox&themeId=Theme_INESPCORPtheme_WAR_Theme_INESPCORPtheme&minifierType=css&languageId=es_ES&b=6205&t=1536758494000 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://XXXXX/group/espaciocorporativo-staging/centro-deportivo
Cookie: COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=es_ES; SCREEN_NAME=62583670354c526441445853737a31635368746179413d3d; _ga=GA1.4.2117709036.1533115603; _ga=GA1.2.819564883.1533118883; LOGIN=78323632363637; USER_UUID=69793777764437457a4e7473766f43744c5759382b526f7563387a32576757744f635a4571654d30636d633d; COMPANY_ID=20157; ID=5a586d61316864306d694a666262673162336e3474513d3d; PASSWORD=39437449474759444e586c7258665a43465538327a773d3d; REMEMBER_ME=true; JSESSIONID=60C696C9BBFFEA286C75862571DC3401; LFR_SESSION_STATE_20161=1536823187622; _gid=GA1.4.1226222595.1536824093
Host: XXXXX
X-Forwarded-Host: XXXX
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Forwarded: for=180.93.30.9;host=XXXXX;proto=http
X-Forwarded-For:XXXXX
Connection: close

]
Sep 13, 2018 8:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter parsePathParameters
FINE: The variable [uriBC] has value [/Theme_INESPCORP-theme/css/main.css]
Sep 13, 2018 8:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter parsePathParameters
FINE: The variable [semicolon] has value [-1]
Sep 13, 2018 8:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter parsePathParameters
FINE: The variable [enc] has value [utf-8]
Sep 13, 2018 8:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter parseSessionCookiesId
**FINE:  (sn3) This request have [0] cookies**
```

You can see this horrible result:
**FINE:  (sn3) This request have [0] cookies**

So, reviewing apache code, and without any ERROR TRACE in execution... cookies are retrieved in this point:

> ServerCookies serverCookies = request.getServerCookies();
>
> ...
>
> public ServerCookies getServerCookies()   {
>       parseCookies();
>       return this.coyoteRequest.getCookies();   }
>
> ....
>
> cookieProcessor.parseCookieHeader(this.coyoteRequest.getMimeHeaders(),
>   serverCookies);
>
> ....

I use legacyCookieProccesor and parseCookieHeader method don't print this line:

```
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("Cookies: Parsing b[]: " + cookieValue.toString());
    }
```

So.. or I have lost all headers, or at least I have lost "Cookie" mime-header.

I have launched in my test n request (35455 in last test for example) exactly identical that runs correctly, reading and parsing cookies... and in number 35456 request it lost this cookie that is correctly informed, like you can see, in "Received [" debug trace of org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer class

Friends! Any idea? Exactly place for add more trace, any tomcat parameter that change the headers parse behaviour, any idea of openshift - tomcat relationship... I don't know how to continue, except add more and more traces to tomcat

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Honestly 8.0.24 is kind of old.  Try it on 8.0.53 and see if the issue remains.

Comment: well, all Tomcat 8.0.x are [quite old](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html). *if* you try a newer version rather go for the latest 8.5 release. I'd need some more context to the code you're adding. Also, make sure that this isn't a problem with any reverse proxy and the log output just misguides you (e.g. due to concurrent logging of many different requests, which might hide the actual request.

Comment: Hi! Im try to explain better. When system begins to fail, i know with totally certainly that request lost my cookies. Request is parsed on AbstractNioInputBuffer class, that at start of parse process print the classic tomcat debug log: